# arduino uno fast pwm pin5/6

Tags: c, arduino, arduino-uno, pwm

I'm using `timer0` to create a fast pwm on digital pin `5/6`.

I managed to get a static pwm.

The next task is to change between the values 50 to 200 and back 50 and so on.

Here occurs a problem. If I spectate the values generated at the pin, the pwm is often the size 50 and then it changes to 200. 
If I print the values on the serial monitor I get the wanted values back.

**QUESTION**

How do I have to change my code to get the pwm of `50 --> 200 --> 50`?

***Code***

```c
#include <avr/io.h>           // this header is necessary to adress the registers
#include <avr/interrupt.h>    // this header is necessary for the ISR 

int pin5 = 5;
int pin6 = 6;

bool changestate = true;

int state1 = 50;
int state2 = 200;

void setup() 
{
    Serial.begin(9600);
    pinMode(pin5, OUTPUT);
    pinMode(pin6, OUTPUT);

    noInterrupts();
    TCCR0A = 0b10000011;  //2^7: non inverting mode. 2^0,2^1: for wgm--> fast pwm 
    TCCR0B = 0b00000001;  //2^3=0: wgm02 off. 2^0: no prescaler
    OCR0A = state1;          //statische Pulsweite
    TIMSK0 = 0b00000010;   //TOV0 is set when overflow occurs. 
    interrupts();
}

void loop() 
{
// put your main code here, to run repeatedly:
}

ISR(TIMER0_COMPA_vect)
{
    Serial.println(OCR0A);
    if(changestate == true)
    {
        OCR0A = state2;
    } 
    else
    {
        OCR0A = state1;
    }
    changestate = !changestate;
}
```

[image: Oszi values at pin]
[image: serial monitor output]

Comment: What is wrong with the code? It seems to do what you want?

Comment: well yes. it kind of does what i want. on the other hand if you look at the oszilloskope picture you can see, that the pulses do not change from 50 to 200 and back. there are a lot of 50 pulses and then comes a sudden change and only 200 pulses. that is what is driving me crazy.

Comment: remove println() from interrupt

Comment: @Juraj i implemented this only because i wanted to check the function of the isr. my main emphasis would still be the picture of the oscilloscope. the output is not reflecting what i am expecting and i doubt that removing println() would change that.

Comment: the println takes time and the PWM runs. interrupts are missed

Comment: @Juraj alright. thank you for the assistance. i will try this out. but i still think, that the problem will remain. if i m not mistaking did i implement the println() after the oszilloscpe bad results. i keep you updated. do you have another idea why it could not work properly?

Comment: right now I don't understand what should trigger the interrupt and when, because you set bits of registers by position instead of using constants and I don't hae time to study the datasheet

Comment: @Juraj the interrupt is triggert if the ocr0a has the same value as the timer0. yes i set bits. i saw a different notation but i didnt really understand it (like this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45946688/avr-timer1-16bit-fast-pwm). Any recommendation where to learn this notation?

Comment: "the interrupt is triggert if the ocr0a has the same value as the timer0". of course, but when is it same? I see "no prescaler" comment and ocr0a is 50 or 200

Comment: If you want smooth operation quit messing with the toy arduino language, use C, and don't do anything in an interrupt but change a value of a volatile variable.

Comment: @Juraj yes, there is no prescaler, but the timer runs anyways. If bit 0,1 and 2 would be 0 the timer0 would be stopped according to the datasheet.

Comment: @TomServo ok, thank you for the hint. can i programm an arduino directly with c? for this project i m working on it is necessary to use an arduino uno.